# Rewrite all URL to index.php except from '/Serene/Assets/'

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I've currently got all my URL's redirecting to index.php with this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

However, I need URLs such as `http://localhost/Portfolio/Serene/Assets/css/style.css` to not redirect, but I'm not sure how?

I'd really appreciate any help,

Cheers.

EDIT: Alternatively, I could tell the htaccess to not redirect any .js, .css, image files, etc, but again, I'm not too sure how to do this? 
Thanks!

EDIT2: I could also redirect anything ending in a .php or a path (such as /Portfolio/) to index.php, I have a feeling this may be easier.

EDIT3: Success, final code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a another way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

images, robots.txt won't be rewritten to index.php. Just add your directories/files.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cheers! That code persay didn't help, but all I needed to know was that `!` means redirect everything but the following. Here's the final code for anyone interested:


    `RewriteEngine on`

    `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f`
    
    `RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 6):

This will rewrite requests for any files that don't exist on the server to index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```