# Effect Permalink .htaccess to load css file

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, hyperlink, permalinks

i have

> localhost/ctr/index.php?page=reload

and i use htaccess to convert them into

> localhost/ctr/index/reload

htaccess it is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule index/([a-z]+) index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

This work, the page with the url of the new format appears.

but there is a problem to load the css file as follows:

```
link href="templates/plugin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
```

I think the css file load is influenced arrangements that I made in htaccess.

how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Try this [rewrite-all-url-to-index-php-except-from-serene-assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543423/rewrite-all-url-to-index-php-except-from-serene-assets)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the link to make it absolute:

```
link href="/templates/plugin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
```

Or you need to add the proper URI base in page header:

```
<base href="/">
```